# Proof of first Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

Can you please, check if my proof is correct?

> Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous and $F(x)=\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt$, then  $F\in C^{1}[a,b]$ and 
>   $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt:=F'(x)=f(x)$$

**MY PROOF: Credits to Aweygan for the correction**

Let $x_0\in[a,b]$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|t-x_0|<\delta$ implies $$|f(t)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.$$
Thus,  $$f(x_0)=\dfrac{1}{x-x_0}\int^{x}_{x_0}f(x_0)dt,\;\;\text{where}\;\;x\neq x_0.$$
For any $x\in (a,b),$ with $0<|x-x_0|<\delta,$ such that $x_1=\min\{x,x_0\}$ and $x_2=\max\{x,x_0\}$. So, we have
\begin{align}\left| \dfrac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f(x_0) \right|&=  \left| \dfrac{1}{x-x_0}\int^{x}_{x_0}(f(t)-f(x_0))dt \right|  \\&\leq  \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\int^{x}_{x_0} \left|f(t)-f(x_0) \right|dt\\&\leq  \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\int^{x_2}_{x_1} \left|f(t)-f(x_0) \right|dt\\&< \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\epsilon|x_1-x_2| \\&\leq \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\epsilon|x-x_0| =\epsilon  \end{align}
Hence, 
$$F\in C^{1}[a,b]\;\;\text{and}\;\;\dfrac{d}{dx}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt:=F'(x)=f(x)$$

Comment: It's not sufficient to prove the limit is $f(x)$ only from one side.

Comment: You still only have differentiability from the right, you need to show differentiability from the left (i.e. when $-\delta<h<0$).

Comment: You're still computing a one-sided limit.

Comment: It's still not quite correct.  I'm all but certain you'll need to handle the two cases $h>0$ and $h<0$ separately, or introduce some new variables to avoid this.

Comment: @Aweygan: I want to rewrite it, now. Some moments, please!

Comment: @egreg: Can you, please, check now?

Comment: @Aweygan: You can check it now!

Comment: @BigbearZzz: Thanks a lot for the edit! How is it now?

Comment: Almost right, but the limits of integration after the first inequality don't reflect whether $x<x_0$ or $x_0<x$.

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal I posted an answer to better explain what I was thinking.  Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Yes, I got your response. That was nice!

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly use the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals):
$$
\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt-\int_{a}^{x+h}f(t)dt}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{f(c_{h})h}{h}
$$
where $c_{h}$ is between $x$ and $x+h$. Therefore, $\lim_{h\downarrow0}c_{h}=x$.
By continuity, $\lim_{h\downarrow0}f(c_{h})=f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially correct, but you should either split up the last part of the proof into the cases where $x<x_0$ and $x_0<x$, or write $x_1=\min\{x,x_0\}$, $x_2=\max\{x,x_0\}$ and do the following:

\begin{align}
\left| \dfrac{F(x)-F(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f(x_0) \right|&=  \left| \dfrac{1}{x-x_0}\int^{x}_{x_0}(f(t)-f(x_0))dt \right|  \\
&\leq  \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\int^{x_2}_{x_1} \left|f(t)-f(x_0) \right|dt
\\&< \dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}\epsilon|x-x_0| \\
&=\epsilon.  
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation (+1)

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!